# Ubuntu won't boot after livepatchd snap app fails

Tags: boot, canonical-livepatch

Whenever I try to boot Ubuntu, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPXn.png) appears; it halts after the snap app livepatchd fails several times.

How may I troubleshoot this?